# Software for quickly and simply re-coloring and resizing a PNG image

Tags: color, icon, software-recommendation, image-processing

Let's say I'm given an image of a flat colored icon, which is a 512x512 PNG black icon. Is there a software to **quickly and simply** generate e.g. a 36x36 (arbitrary) red (or any color) version of the same icon? Such like macOS' Preview, which is quick to open and from there is straight forward. I find it overkill to fire up GIMP or Photoshop for what feels like such a simple task. Preferably on macOS.

Comment: Why do you think that GIMP is an overkill?

Comment: @JohnDvorak AFAIK it provides tools for color correction but I've yet to find a simple way to change the entire image's color while keeping its alpha. Having to make a selection by alpha and making a new layer, select my new color and fill it in, requires too many steps for me to be patient with :)

Comment: Use SVG and change the color in CSS.

Comment: @Scott Although the images are PNGs

Comment: I understand that. But certain formats take a certain amount of work. It's merely inherent due to formats. If Gimp is too much... I'd be curious as to what would be *less* overhead and can alter PNG color. I mean, pretty much anything is going to have the same relative overhead as GIMP. I suppose apps such as GraphicsConverter *might* be a tad smaller. Also, if you have Preview and seem to indicate it works for your needs in your question, what's wring with using Preview?

Comment: @Scott The way I see it, what both GIMP and Preview are excellent at is tinting an image which would work if the original image was white colored, however in our case above we start off with a black colored icon and want to change the entire color while keeping the alpha, pretty much.

Comment: Yeah. I get it `:)` However, because it's a raster image you are going to *have* to create a selection which means more work. It's *always* a simple matter to *darken* a color without a selection. But as soon as you want to *lighten* a color you need a selection. That selection can be based upon alpha easily. but then you get into areas the "tiny" apps aren't capable of. I **think** you could possible script such a thing with [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/), (which is free) but I'm not experienced enough with it to be certain.

Comment: Many people choose Gimp and Photoshop because that is less work for them. That is theres less up front investment but more work over many repeats. There's no real answer for your question since it does not tell me what is acceptable amount of work? Now is imagemagic Suggested by Scott overkill? After all imagemagick has a scope that is atleast as big as gimp if not bigger. So how would we know what is not overkill by you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since OP gave no parameters of what is an acceptable amount of work and is expecting some magically tiny software

Answer (score 1):

In your comments you mention that you have yet to find "a simple way to change the entire image's color while keeping its alpha" in GIMP.

However that is fairly simple task.

In GIMP, open the image, make sure the Image mode is RGB by clicking *Image > Mode* and that check that RGB is selected.

Then click *Edit > Colorize*, then move the hue, saturation or lightness sliders to colour the icon as you wish, or alternatively use the colour selector. It will not affect the alpha channel at all.

Here's an example where I turn a monochrome (black and white) icon into a bright red icon.

[image]

Resizing images is also simple. Click *Image > Scale Image*, and change the size.  Remember that scaling raster images will decrease their quality. If you find yourself scaling images often, probably better to look into using vector image editing software such as Inkscape (which is also free and Open Source), or Illustrator (not free). Vectors can be resized smaller or larger without degradation in quality.

Note: If you are using Photoshop, the same is also possible, but the colorize option is in the Hue-Saturation adjustment dialog, and image sizing is under *Image > Image Size*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that at least two ways with Photoshop.

Create an Action in Photoshop for the change.

Then in File>Automate you can either use "Batch" or "Create a Droplet". In these menus, you specify how you want them to processed, meaning do you want them saved over the old files? or duplicates made before processing and then saved not another folder/directory?

Batch will let you control the processing while Photoshop is open. A Droplet is a special mini-app it creates that you can just drag and drop your files onto and the Action will be performed on all of them.

Depending on the variety, you might need to create a few different Batches or Droplets for the different steps or final versions you need.